# Wordpress Theme issue

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system, themes, wordpress-theming

I am facing a weird issue. I am building my site using a wordpress theme.

Even the desired theme has pictures (http://themehorse.com/preview/ultimate), but when i activate it to be used in my site, not all tabs, and all pictures are not downloaded at all.

My site is http://www.zeidny.com/

Do anyone know why i am facing such issue in wordpress.

Thanks all for your help,
Ahmad Osman

Answer (score 0):

Most themes doesn't come with the data, thats mostly because the image or articles have copyrights for one site usage only. In order to get the images and data on your website, you will have to use the data import file that comes with the theme. SO all you have to do is goto the admin area, **click on tools>wordpress import and upload the data file**.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect that all pictures and contents of the theme's live preview site are automatically on your page? Then you have to get the data set of the live preview site and import it on yours.

Your site seems to work fine, the only error message shown in the inspectors console is/(was) the missing favicon.ico:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thanks Omer, and Robin for your help.

As this is the first time i have ever used wordpress, please correct me if i am wrong, I expect i can use the theme exactly with all pictures,and contents in my site, then using tools, i can edit them?

Then yes Robin, i expect that..do u know how to do so, or if there is a doc to guide me.

Thanks all for your help,

Comment: To have the exact same pictures and contents like the preview page, you should ask the theme seller for the sample data.

Second possibility would be to manually input all of the pages and its content, but then you ll have the question if it s allowed => copyright etc.

The purpose of content and images/pictures of themes at preview pages  is to showcase the possibilities of the theme and not to provide content for the theme user/buyer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your clarification Robin.

Then can i find free themes in wordpress?, or all themes provide partial function?

Thanks again all for your help,

Comment: Themes provide different functionality, but you ll find a lot of similarities across different themes.
To find free themes browse https://wordpress.org/themes/ or search via google.

Comment: Thanks Robin for your help. I am very astonished that there is no free theme in wordpress..i tried to search for them like https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/sort/free/, but still couldn't find.

Will u advise plz.
Thanks,

Comment: please note the difference between wordpress.com and wordpress.org, visit the link i ve provided you in an upper comment: https://wordpress.org/themes/

There are 100s of 1000s free themes out there.